# Python converting the values from dicts into a tuples

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I have a list of dictionaries that looks like this:

```
[{'id':1,'name':'Foo'},{'id':2,'name':'Bar'}]
```

I'd like to convert the values from each dict into a list of tuples like this:

```
[(1,'Foo'),(2,'Bar')]
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
>>> l = [{'id':1,'name':'Foo'},{'id':2,'name':'Bar'}]
>>> [tuple(d.values()) for d in l]
[(1, 'Foo'), (2, 'Bar')]
```

Comment: @Marco: it gives consistent order for given keys, there is nothing wrong about this answer.

Comment: You can't guarantee `id` will always come out before `name`, especially across different versions/implementations. For example entering the above example in IronPython (eg. trypython.org) currently gives `[('Foo', 1), ('Bar', 2)]`. You can't even be sure that two dicts with the same keys will give their `keys()` in the same order (they will for simple cases like this, but that's an implementation detail you're not supposed to rely on).

Comment: This works now, `Dictionaries preserve insertion order. Note that updating a key does not affect the order. Keys added after deletion are inserted at the end.` [link](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values)

Answer (score 13):

Note that the approach in SilentGhost's answer doesn't guarantee the order of each tuple, since dictionaries and their `values()` have no inherent order. So you might just as well get `('Foo', 1)` as `(1, 'Foo')`, in the general case.

If that's not acceptable and you definitely need the `id` first, you'll have to do that explicitly:

```
[(d['id'], d['name']) for d in l]
```

Answer (score 3):

This will convert the dictionary to tuple always in defined `order`

`d = {'x': 1 , 'y':2}
order = ['y','x']
tuple([d[field] for field in order])`

Comment: dicts are now ordered (recent python-standard promise), so this is now unnecessary.